# Block someone 100% from my Gmail

Tags: gmail

I recently got into an ugly argument with someone and now I wish to block them and remove them from my Gmail and chats. How can this be done?

Comment: What do you mean by "block from my gmail"? Prevent that person from sending you email messages? And by "chats" are you referring to "Google Hangouts"? In Hangouts you do have the option to block a contact.

Comment: I think the question is clear.  Chris doesn't want to have to read inflammatory, upsetting messages from the person.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For email: make a filter for messages from that address.  Skip the inbox and put the messages directly in the trash.

For chat: I'm sorry, I know nothing about chat.